# Ways to get stdout from sub processes of a child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am create a child process which initiates child processes of it's own. Is there any way to capture the stdout of them all? I can not edit the source code of the application I am running.

They should all be in the same process group. I know the process id's of all the processes I wish to capture stdout from.

Comment: Can we see your code? And what do you mean by "a sub process of a child process?"

Comment: Formulated my sentence differently. I am trying to capture the output of all the child process that I created, but also of the child processes that it may create. Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: Whether you can do that depends on what the immediate child process does to spawn its children, and specifically whether it allows its children to inherit its `stdout` or explicitly opens a file. If it opens a file, you won't be able to capture the "grand-child" process output.

Comment: How would go about doing this if the application allowed it? Are you able to attach to a process' stdout whilst it is running?

Comment: Well, if the parent process allows its child processes to inherit its `stdout` value (like what a shell like `bash` would do by default), you'll automatically get all child process output.